# Test for dictionary terms Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want use a dictionary so that i can test if a word is in it and if it is return the definition. For example if `var dictionary = ["a":"B"]` I want to see if "a" exists in the dictionary and if it does print "B". Any ideas on how I could achieve this in Swift 2.2 would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Read the language guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if let` statement:

```
let key = "a"

if let definition = dictionary[key] {
   print(definition)
}
else {
   print("no definition for \(key)")
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `let key = "a"`

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell No need to downvote over a puny mistake. You can just suggest and edit and fix it yourself.

Comment: FYI, I didn't. I have no idea who down voted you. However, I was waiting for that fix before I upvoted.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell This answer is so simple to be wrong lol Somebody must have been feeling mean :(

Comment: Fixed. Had to chance `\{key}` to `\(key)`

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of resources out there that show you how to do this. It is quite simple.

```
let dict = ["a" : "first", "b" : "second", "c" : "third", "d" : "fourth", "e" : "fifth"]

if let temp = dict["a"] {
    print("value = \(temp)")
}
```

Comment: why is this getting down voted? it answers the question

Comment: I was trying to figure out the downvotes, too. Maybe your dictionary isn't formed correctly?

Comment: fair enough, I was looking at my xCode playground on one screen and retyping onto my windows computer on the other screen. 

not everything deserves downvotes

Comment: Yes it does. Downvotes indicate a wrong answer, inaccurate code, etc. Your example didn't even compile. Now it's fixed: downvote canceled. *This is exactly how it's supposed to work on this site.*

Comment: no problems, sorry. just trying to eke out some street creds on the ol' overflow, and in an effort to earn some reps I may have been hasty in my typing. I'll watch it closer next time.